# Is it possible to program Arduino boards using a few lines of assembly in the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino

I want to measure the time between two signals that are not in phase and i am using arduino Uno. I have converted the 2 sinusoidal signals into square waves and i am feeding them on INT0 and INT1 respectively. To measure the lag between the two signals i want to measure the time between the rising edges or falling edges of the signals using interrupts. On receiving the first rising edge i want to start a timer, say timer 3, upon receiving the second rising edge i want to stop the timer. my problem is i cant find a library that will allow me to start and stop timer the 3 and use the value it so i have chosen to include a few lines of Assembly language in my program for that purpose. Is it possible on the Arduino boards using the arduino IDE?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible.  See for example [this tutorial.](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/arduino-inline-assembly-tutorial-1/)  However, I'd strongly recommend if you're doing anything more than a few instructions, you download and install Atmel studio -- which is free -- and use its excellent user interface to do your coding and debugging.  I do all my programming for bare microcontrollers, in-system programming, and Arduinos using Atmel Studio.